# Add text to the bottom of particular pages

Tags: pages, content

I want to add

```
[one_third][responsive]
<a href="http://weburl.com/lifestyle">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-176" alt="courses" src="http://weburl.com/img/buttons/courses.png" width="310" height="109" /></a>
[/responsive][/one_third]
[one_third][responsive]
<a href="http://weburl.com/answers/landing-pages/">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-178" alt="tools" src="http://weburl.com/img/buttons/tools.png" width="310" height="109" /></a>
[/responsive][/one_third]
[one_third_last][responsive]
<a href="http://weburl.com/entrepreneurship">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-179" alt="videos" src="http://weburl.com/img/buttons/videos.png" width="310" height="109" /></a>
[/responsive][/one_third_last]
```

In the bottom of all the pages parent to my Entrepreneurship page.

Is their a way to add it to the pages parent to entrepreneurship without going on every single page and paste it at the bottom?

---

I used this code below but its also showing in the Entrepreuneurship page and I wanted it to only show in the parent pages of entrepreneurship but that's oke I can hide it in the entrepreneurship page by css (display: none;)

FYI my page ID is 267 and to recapitulate what I wanted is to have a code inserted in the bottom of the pages parent to 267 (entrepreneurship).

If someone can improve this code it would help me very much.

Thanks.

```
            <?php
            $entrepreneurshipObject = get_page_by_title( 'Entrepreneurship' );
            $entrepreneurshipID = $entrepreneurshipObject->ID;
            $shortcode = '<div class="buttonsEntrepreneurship"><div class="one_third"><span class="responsive"> <a href="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/lifestyle"> <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-176" alt="courses" src="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/img/buttons/courses.png" width="310" height="109"></a> </span></div> <div class="one_third"><span class="responsive"> <a href="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/answers/landing-pages/"> <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-178" alt="tools" src="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/img/buttons/tools.png" width="310" height="109"></a> </span></div> <div class="one_third last"><span class="responsive"> <a href="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/entrepreneurship"> <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-179" alt="videos" src="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/img/buttons/videos.png" width="310" height="109"></a> </span></div></div>';

            if($post->ID == $entrepreneurshipID || $post->post_parent == $entrepreneurshipID){
                echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the page ID we can directly look page ID `267` - so let's skip the searching for an ID and jump to the comparison:

You mentioned that you do not want it on the Entrepreneurship page, so lets only look for pages where the parent is ID `267`

```
if($post->post_parent == 267)
```

It looks like you've removed your shortcode, so let's make this more visually appealing and clean up the code:

```
<?php if($post->post_parent == 267) : ?>
    <div class="buttonsEntrepreneurship">
        <div class="one_third">
            <span class="responsive">
                <a href="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/lifestyle"> 
                    <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-176" alt="courses" src="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/img/buttons/courses.png" width="310" height="109">
                </a> 
            </span>
        </div> 

        <div class="one_third">
            <span class="responsive"> 
                <a href="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/answers/landing-pages/"> 
                    <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-178" alt="tools" src="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/img/buttons/tools.png" width="310" height="109">
                </a> 
            </span>
        </div> 

        <div class="one_third last">
            <span class="responsive"> 
                <a href="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/entrepreneurship"> 
                    <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-179" alt="videos" src="http://collegeisnottheanswer.com/img/buttons/videos.png" width="310" height="109">
                </a> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I posted an update with my page ID.

Comment: There's the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple enough with a filter on `the_content`. I don't quite know what "all the pages parent to my Entrepreneurship page" means but the following will add your string to the bottom of all "Page" post type pages that have parent equal 0-- that is, parent pages. You can tweak the `if` conditions to get the exact behavior you need.

```
function append_to_page_wpse($content) {
  global $post;
  if (
    'page' == $post->post_type
    && 0 === $post->post_parent
  ) {
    $content .= '[one_third][responsive] <a href="http://weburl.com/lifestyle"> <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-176" alt="courses" src="http://weburl.com/img/buttons/courses.png" width="310" height="109" /></a> [/responsive][/one_third] [one_third][responsive] <a href="http://weburl.com/answers/landing-pages/"> <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-178" alt="tools" src="http://weburl.com/img/buttons/tools.png" width="310" height="109" /></a> [/responsive][/one_third] [one_third_last][responsive] <a href="http://weburl.com/entrepreneurship"> <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-179" alt="videos" src="http://weburl.com/img/buttons/videos.png" width="310" height="109" /></a> [/responsive][/one_third_last]';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','append_to_page_wpse');
```

This should run early enough that shortcodes process normally without any special manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your response @s_ha_dum . I updated my post, I hope its more clear what I want.